# SSRS: Using temp tables in the SSRS report query

Tags: mysql, sql, reporting-services

I have an SSRS query that uses temp table and a select statement that returns output , when i try to modify the query and refresh the fields in the Dataset properties window  i get following error

"Could not update the list of fields for the query.Verify that you cannot connect to Datasurce and that your query syntax is correct". I am able to connect to datasource and I was able t execute query in sql server management studio . I could see all the fields of report are appearing , but unable to refresh.

My question is can we use temp tables in report query (where Query Type : text) in Dataset properties Window ? Will it work

I was also able to build report successfully this means my fields are refreshed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the error you're seeing is because SSRS is trying to determine the shape of the query output without running the query, which means the temp table doesn't exist. You might try previewing the query in SSRS and then see if you can update the fields list.